# scraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is a sample html page source code

```
<html><body><div class="a-section a-spacing-medium a-spacing-top-small" id="feature-bullets">
<ul class="a-vertical a-spacing-none">
<li><span class="a-list-item"> Material: Cotton ; Colour: Light blue</span>     </li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> Closure Type: Zip</span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> Fit Type: Slim Fit</span></li>
</ul>
</div></body></html>
```

How to get  colour value (light blue) from this html page using Beautifulsoup ?

color = soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'a-vertical a-spacing-none'}).get('a-list-item')

Comment: Can we see what you've tried? It is a good thing that you know to use BeautifulSoup instead of regex

Comment: Can you share your Python code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup` parser.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<html><body><div class="a-section a-spacing-medium a-spacing-top-small" id="feature-bullets">
<ul class="a-vertical a-spacing-none">
<li><span class="a-list-item"> Material: Cotton ; Colour: Light blue</span>     </li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> Closure Type: Zip</span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> Fit Type: Slim Fit</span></li>
</ul>
</div></body></html>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
>>> txt = [i.text for i in soup.select('.a-vertical .a-list-item')]
>>> txt
[u' Material: Cotton ; Colour: Light blue', u' Closure Type: Zip', u' Fit Type: Slim Fit']
>>> import re
>>> next(re.search(r'Colour\s*:\s*([^;]+)', j).group(1) for j in txt if 'Colour' in j )
u'Light blue'
>>>
```